# Poisson brackets for function of function

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics, quantum-mechanics, canonical-transformation

I have a problem which I am finding difficult to derive. I think I am missing something.

Assuming that the Poisson Bracket for two functions $(u, v)$ is defined on the canonical coordinates and momenta $(q_{1},\cdots, q_{n}, p_{1},\cdots,p_{n})$ as follows

$$ (u,v)=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{r=n}\left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial q_{r}}\frac{\partial v}{\partial p_{r}}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial p_{r}}\frac{\partial v}{\partial q_{r}} \right), $$

we need to prove the following statement:

**The problem:**
if $F$ and $\phi$ are functions of $(f_{1},f_{2},\cdots,f_{k})$, which in turn are functions of the canonical set $(q_{1},\cdots, q_{n}, p_{1},\cdots,p_{n})$, **show that**

$$ (F,\phi)=\sum\limits_{r,s} \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial f_{r}}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial f_{s}}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial f_{s}}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial f_{r}} \right) (f_{r},f_{s}) \ \ \ \ ............. (*).$$

**My attempt:**
Whenever I try to work this out, starting from the definition of the bracket for $(F,\phi)$ and then writing the terms like $\frac{\partial F}{\partial q_{k}}$ as $\sum_{r}\frac{\partial F}{\partial f_{r}}\frac{\partial f_{r}}{\partial q_{k}}$, and $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial p_{k}}$ as $\sum_{s}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial f_{s}}\frac{\partial f_{s}}{\partial p_{k}}$, and so on, then collecting terms, I end up with the result

$$ (F,\phi)=\sum\limits_{k}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial q_{k}}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial p_{k}}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial p_{k}}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial q_{k}} \right)=\sum\limits_{k}\left(\sum_{r} \frac{\partial F}{\partial f_{r}}\frac{\partial f_{r}}{\partial q_{k}}\sum_{s}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial f_{s}}\frac{\partial f_{s}}{\partial p_{k}}-\sum_{s}\frac{\partial F}{\partial f_{s}}\frac{\partial f_{s}}{\partial p_{k}}\sum_{r}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial f_{r}}\frac{\partial f_{r}}{\partial q_{k}} \right)$$

$$= \sum\limits_{r,s} \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial f_{r}}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial f_{s}}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial f_{s}}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial f_{r}} \right)\sum\limits_{k} \frac{\partial f_{r}}{\partial q_{k}}\frac{\partial f_{s}}{\partial p_{k}} .$$

But, as you can see when comparing with equation (*) above, only the term in the large bracket is correctly reached, and there is a missing term to complete the bracket for $(f_{r},f_{s})$. I don't seem able to trace its origin here. Any help would be appreciated.

This exercise is found in Whittaker's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521358833) on Analytical Dynamics (p. 300).

Comment: There were some errors/mixing up in my typed equation lines in the original posting - apologies. it is now cleared (updated) in the posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an error in the exercise; it’s missing a factor $\frac12$.

This sort of thing is often most easily cleared up by substituting a simple example instead of trying to chase the error through the complicated general expressions. If you substitute $F=f_1$ and $\phi=f_2$, the result should be $(f_1,f_2)$, but the formula you quote from the exercise yields $2(f_1,f_2)$ (one contribution each for $(r,s)\in\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$). (Alternatively, the sum should be over $r\lt s$ instead of $r,s$.)

You can see that your result is half their result by noting that the first factor is antisymmetric in $r$ and $s$, so you can double the result by subtracting the same expression with $r$ and $s$ exchanged, which completes the second factor.

Comment: 1/2: This's a nice answer -thanks. However, I'm afraid of taking it for 3 reasons. (1) the book is a monument of classical dynamics that has been scrutinized by generations repeatedly (that doesn't mean, of course, it couldn't have errors, but it is a bit unlikely); (2) I think it is automatically understood that $r /neq s$ because then the Poisson bracket $(f_{s},f_{s})$ contribution is identically zero, thus there is no harm in keeping this case in the summation; and most importantly (3) if this exercise had an error, then a fundamental corollary in mechanics that is similar would be wrong..

Comment: 2/2... namely, that the Poisson bracket of two functions $u,v$ must be invariant under canonical transform from the set $(q1,...,qn, p1,...,pn)$ to the set $(Q1,...,Qn,P1,...,Pn)$, when we will need to have $(u,v)_{p,q}=(u,v)_{Q,P}$, with $(Pi,Pi)=(Qi,Qi)=0$, $(Pi,Qj)=0$ (for $i \neq j)$ and $(Qi,Pi)=1$. As when we try to start with $(u,v)_{Q,P}$ and write it in terms of $q,p$ variables, we will have exactly the same problem, and we cannot put a factor of 1/2 here, because it is not supposed to be there, as is well known from classical canonical transformations on this bracket.

Comment: To clarify 2/2 above, here is a similar well-known problem: If the set $\bar{q},\bar{p}$ is canonically transformed to $\bar{Q},\bar{P}$, so that the we have in Poisson brackets: $(P_{i},P_{j})=0,(Q_{i},Q_{j})=0$ (for any $i,j$) and $(Q_{i},P_{j})=0$ (for any $i\neq j$) and $(Q_{i},P_{i})=1$, show that we must have:

Comment: $\sum_{r}(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial Q_{r}}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial P_{r}}-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial P_{r}}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial Q_{r}})=\sum_{r}(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial q_{r}}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial p_{r}}-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial p_{r}}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial q_{r}})$, for any two functions $\phi$ and $\psi$, which proves the invariance of the Poisson bracket under canonical transform.  Notice that calculating this will lead to the same issue I mentioned above in my post. Yet, we cannot add a factor of (1/2) here because the form is invariant.

Comment: Take $(f_1,\ldots,f_{2n}) = (Q_1,\ldots,Q_n,P_1,\ldots,P_n)$. Then equation $(\ast)$ will give $(F,\phi)_{(q,p)} = \sum_{i,j=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial Q_i}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial P_j} - \frac{\partial F}{\partial P_j}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial Q_i}\right)(Q_i,P_j) +\sum_{i,j=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial P_i}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial Q_j} - \frac{\partial F}{\partial Q_j}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial P_i}\right)(P_i,Q_j)$ This simplifies to  $2(F,\phi)_{(Q,P)}$, not $(F,\phi)_{(Q,P)}$ as you want.

Comment: In other words, joriki is correct - there's a missing factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in $(\ast)$.

Comment: @user17945 I don't understand why did you have two summation terms here by applying (\*) ? This will lead to a factor of 2, yes, but how did these two summations appear in the first place if we use (\*)? Note that the sum in (\*) is over all combinations of $f_{s}$ and $f_{r}$.

Comment: When you sum over all the variables $f_r,f_s$ you get four types of terms: $(Q_i,Q_j), (Q_i,P_j), (P_i,Q_j),$ and $(P_i,P_j)$. The first and last vanish, the remaining two are what I wrote.

Comment: @user17945  Oh, I see it now! This is just brilliant! I really appreciate it - thank you. By the way, may I take your opinion about the best books to master this field of classical dynamics/mechanics? If you had limited time and could only study one important book, which one would you study it from? For example, I am split between recommendations to study Whittaker's classic (Analytical Dynamics), Arnold's (Math Methods of classical mechanics) and Goldstein's. Any advice on this? Especially if it includes some coverage of perturbation theory and Lie transformations. Or any other suggestions?

Comment: @user135626: You were right about $r\ne s$; I meant "all pairs of $r$ and $s$ with $r\ne s$"; I've changed it to $r\lt s$. I'm glad the substantial issue has been cleared up. (By the way, I studied physics, I know that canonical transforms don't have a factor of $\frac12$, but you couldn't know that :-)