# canonical transformation

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics, quantum-mechanics, hamilton-equations, canonical-transformation

A system of Hamiltonian equations in generalized coordinate $q$ and momentum $p$ is given by

$$ \frac{d q}{d t}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}, \ \ \ \ \frac{d p}{d t}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q} $$

where $H=\frac{1}{2} (p^{2}+k^{2}q^{2}).$

Show that the canonical transform from $q,p$ to $Q,P$ given by
$$ q=\sqrt{2Q/k} \ \cos P, \ \ \ \ p=\sqrt{2Qk} \ \sin P, $$

will result in a new Hamiltonian system of equations given by 
$$ \frac{d Q}{d t}=\frac{\partial K}{\partial P}, \ \ \ \ \frac{d P}{d t}=-\frac{\partial K}{\partial Q}, $$

where $K=kQ$ ?

I have been unable to solve this seemingly simple problem (it comes from Whittaker's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521358833), p.307). In my calculations, I get a tangent function, namely, $dQ/dt=(dP/dt) \ (2Q \tan 2P)$.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hamilton's equations in $(q,p)$ coordinates give
$$
\dot{q} = p, \qquad \dot{p} = -k^2q.
$$
Inverting the coordinate transformation gives
$$
Q=\frac{1}{2k}(p^2+k^2q^2), \qquad P = \tan^{-1}\frac{p}{kq}
$$
(the latter expression for $q>0$; other quadrants of the $(q,p)$-plane are related by $\pm\pi$). Then
$$
\dot{Q} = \frac{1}{k}(p\dot{p} + k^2q\dot{q}) = \frac{1}{k}(-k^2pq+k^2qp)=0=\frac{\partial K}{\partial P},
$$
while
$$
\dot{P} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{p^2}{k^2q^2}}\left(\frac{\dot{p}}{kq} -\frac{p\dot{q}}{kq^2}\right) = \frac{1}{1+\frac{p^2}{k^2q^2}}\left(-k-\frac{p^2}{kq^2}\right) = -k = -\frac{\partial K}{\partial Q}.
$$

Comment: Many thanks for this!  I wonder why did my derivation not lead to this that simply when I started by substituting for $q,p$ in the original system in terms of $Q,P$ and then solving for $\dot{Q}, \dot{P}$ (contrary to your approach of writing $Q,P$ in terms of $q,p$ first)? My approach gave me two relations that relate $\dot{Q}$ and $\dot{P}$, namely, $\dot{Q}=\dot{P}(2Q \tan P)$ and $\dot{Q}^{2}+4Q^{2}\dot{P}^{2}=4Q^{2}k^{2}$, which don't give the same $K$.  Do you have any insight or comments about this?

Comment: Can I ask you please to also advise about my other question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586385/poisson-brackets-for-function-of-function

Comment: Following your approach (starting with $\dot{q}=p, \dot{p}=-k^2q$, and subbing in $q(Q,P)$ and $p(Q,P)$), I get two equations $\cos P\,\dot{Q}-2Q\sin P\,\dot{P} = 2Qk\sin P$ and $\sin P\,\dot{Q} + 2Q\cos P\,\dot{P} = -2Qk\cos P$. Solving these simultaneously gives $\dot{Q}=0$ and $\dot{P}=-k$ as before. I'm not sure where your two relations came from.

Comment: For your other question, I agree with joriki's answer (and don't agree with your 2/2 comment).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it appears I made an error while solving these two eqns simultaneously for $\dot{Q}, \dot{P}$... By the way, I don't quite understand the motivation behind your note in brackets above about the $q,p$ quadrants and why picking out the case $q>0$? Isn't it ok to keep it general, since $\arctan$ would accept infinity and negatives arguments?

Comment: The point is that $\tan^{-1}$ has range $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. So if $P = \tan^{-1}\frac{p}{kp}$, then $q=\sqrt{2Q/k}\cos P$ will be $>0$. In general, $P$ should be expressed in terms of the [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function.

Comment: I added a new comment to clarify the comment 2/2 in the post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586385/poisson-brackets-for-function-of-function  , I hope you can see my point now. For if you try solving the poisson invariance in this new comment, you will run in to the same problem and I don't think we can add a factor of half there.